# Lost access to wifi

Tags: wifi

I am using an Alpha Litebook with Eos.  It was funcitoning well.  I tried to update the os via the application centre and it hung before finishing.  Once rebooted, all access to wifi dissappeared.  I am currently plugged i nto an ethernet cable.  When I open network settings, only ethernet shows.  when I click into edit connection, my last wifi connection shows, however there is no way to gain access to it to use.  when I click on the icon on the top of the screen, the only choice is wired.

Any help would be appreciated.

THanks.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:

Open terminal, and type

Nmcli radio wifi on (uncertain if it is an upper or lower case 'N' to be used)

Also, add that line on /etc/rc.local file

I have not tested it as my Litebook had a user on it already that held admin privileges and I was unable to change the text of any of the system files. I ended up downloading the elementary OS from the company website and reinstalling it to get rid of the phantom admin and the wifi works fine.

The touchpad on the other hand....